# NHibernate proxy property access binding

Tags: c#, nhibernate

Is it possible to bind to a "get value" event for every property of a class of the domain model using nhibernate interceptors?
What i would like to do is:
- Have my domain model classes and mappings (nothing new here)
- Using a business layer to handle user requests. This layer should use transactions so a request would behave like this: requst -> open session and transaction -> fulfill request -> commit transaction and close session -> send results back (if any)
- User interacts with data through some kind of GUI. When he asks for some lazy loading data no LazyLoadException (or whatever its name is) is fired because an interceptor is registered and is capable of intercepting the read of a lazy load property. So it opens a nhibernate session and closes it when the read has been performed.

I hope you understand what i mean.
If you desperately need some code samples to clarify i'll try to provide even if i really don't know how to give a programmatic idea.
Any help would be very much appreciated, thanks!

Comment: What platform are you developing for?

Comment: Windows of course. I'm using C# 4.0 with Visual Studio 2010. This question refers to a desktop application.

Comment: Also, i'm using nhibernate version 3.3.2

Answer (score 0):

Our Windows Forms application uses a session per form pattern that works well. In almost all cases we are able to keep just one session open at a time.

In your case, I would investigate using `ISession.Lock` to re-attach the disconnected object to a session to allow lazy loading to work.

Comment: I'm sorry to say that this is not what i asked for... Even if you guessed what i'm trying to achieve here, i want ot do the way i explained. Thanks anyway